# Multiple Select not working since upgrade to TYPO3 6.2 extbase

Tags: typo3, fluid, extbase, typo3-6.2.x

I just checked and the html output seems to be the same for this in my working version back with TYPO3 4.7
I have an appointment that can have multiple students. I add them to a multi-select through an autocomplete textinput-field.

```
<input type="text" id="student-autocomplete"/>
<br/>
<f:form.select  id="selected-students" 
                multiple="true" 
                property="students"
                options="{appointment.students}" 
                optionLabelField="fullName"
                class="" />
```

This is the output - in this example I have added two students.
The input-hidden field seems to be automatically generated by fluid(?):

```
<input type="hidden" value="" name="tx_extname_appoints[appointment][students]">
<select id="selected-students" name="tx_extname_appoints[appointment][students][]" multiple="true">
<option value="160">student1</option>
<option value="52">student 2</option>
</select>
```

Now what I really don't understand is: 
**When I only have one student in my select it works, but when I have multiple I get following error:**

```
Caught exception: Exception while property mapping at property path "students":It is not allowed to map property "1". You need to use $propertyMappingConfiguration->allowProperties('1') to enable mapping of this property.
```

**I'm assuming the "1" refers to my second array index?** But I have no idea what's wrong since it seems to work fine in TYPO3 4.7.
**Should I do something with the *new* property mapper?

Should I try to change some things in my model?**:

```
/**
* students
*
* @var \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\ObjectStorage<\Vendor\ExtName\Domain\Model\Student>
*/
protected $students = NULL;

/**
 * Sets the students
 *
 * @param \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\ObjectStorage<\Vendor\ExtName\Domain\Model\Student> $students
 * @return void
 */
public function setStudents(\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\ObjectStorage $students) {
        $this->students = $students;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't tell the reason, why you see this exception, but you can try to make PropertyMapper a bit relaxed about this collection.

For that you need a `initialize[yourAction]()` method in same controller.

And there you should put something like this:

```
$this->arguments['appointment']
        ->getPropertyMappingConfiguration()
        ->forProperty('students.*')
        ->allowAllProperties();
```

This will tell PropertyMapper not to be strict about 'students' collection property.

Comment: I can't believe it, not only did it erase the error, it even solved the whole problem :D multiple sudents are in the database when I hit save now - thanks!! :) I didn't know you can use "*" in this case, good tip!